# Is there any relation between connectedness of metrizible spaces and their completeness

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness, complete-spaces

I'm new to topology and apologize if my questions might be trivial.

I'm wondering about the causality relation between connected and complete metric spaces. I do wanna know whether the following statements are theorems:
1. If (X,T) is a connected metrizible topological space, then (X,d) (where d is the metric inducing T) is a complete metric space.
2. If (X,d) is a complete metric space, then the topological space (X,T) induced by (X,d) is connected.

Of course these two satements are the converse of each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to both questions is negative. The space $\mathbb{R}\setminus(-1,1)$, with its usual metric, is complete, but disconnected. And $(-1,1)$, with its usual metric, is connected but not complete.

Comment: Thank u so much. I believe that there is also no coonection between the cardinality of the underlying set (specefically being uncountable) and completeness and conndctedness too, am I right?

Comment: @sanazmat Yes, you are right.

Comment: @sanazmat If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry, I'm a bit new here and I don't know how to mark your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: @sanazmat Click the ✓ below the downvote button.